# crystal-reports× 14- Crystal report 2008 sp2 for VS 2008( Parameter issue0

Tags: crystal-reports

very new to crystal reports.. Question is that - In our .net application we view the crystal  report, the report prompts for entering 2 parameter values i.e 2 dates and inturn these parameters will be used to generate the report.

The parameter panel on the left has a button (show advanced dialog box). This button should again invoke the same parameter prompt dialog box, so that the user can modify these parameters and the report can be regenrated.

Issue is that when I click on the the button, this generates a null reference exception in the code.
The call stack is -

```
 at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ParameterFieldInfo.get_isDCP()
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.InteractiveParameterPanel.ShowAdvancedDialog(ParameterUnit pu)
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.InteractiveParameterPanel.pu_ShowAdvancedDialog(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ParameterUnit.OnShowAvancedDialog(EventArgs e)
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ParameterUnit.editControl_ShowAdvancedDialog(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ParameterValueEditControl.OnShowAdvancedDialog(EventArgs e)
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ParameterValueEditControl.btnShowAdvancedDialog_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Please note, I used the .net reflector to debug the crystal report dll , 
the isDCP method looks like -

```
public bool isDCP
    {
      get
      {
        return (this.Attributes.Contains("IsDCP") && ((bool) this.Attributes["IsDCP"]));
      }
    }
```

Looks like the attributes value is null.

Please let me know your comments. Am I missing something while getting the report in the frontend.

I use crystal reports 2008 sp 2 (also note that my gac contains different version of crystal reports (cannot remove them - tried it) , with windows server 2003.
I use web service with proxy to get the report from the local server.

Note I also tried to create sample application  in which I specify the local path to reports source , this works. However when I tried to use webservice, i was getting soap exception.

Please let me know how solve above issue and also how I shoudl create sample application using web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supposed to be an issue with crystal reports. They have noted this issue and hope to fix it future releases

Answer (score 0):

The source report needs to be designed/saved in 2008 format. That "reprompt side window" feature will not work with legacy reports.

Comment: This is supposed to be an issue with crystal reports. They have noted this issue and hope to fix it future releases.